# Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects: Pandas DataFrame Panel

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to average each cell of a bunch of .csv files to export as a single averaged .csv file using Pandas.

I have no problems, creating the dataframe itself, but when I try to turn it into a Panel (i.e. `panel=pd.Panel(dataFrame)`), I get the error: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects pandas pd.panel`

An example of what each csv file looks like:

```
Year, Month, Day, Latitude, Longitude, Value1, Value 2
2010,    06,  01,        23,       97,      1,     3.5
2010,    06,  01,        24,       97,      5,     8.2
2010,    06,  01,        25,       97,      6,     4.6
2010,    06,  01,        26,       97,      4,     2.0
```

Each .csv file is from gridded data so they have the same number of rows and columns, as well as some no data values (given a value of -999.9), which my code snippet below addresses.

The code that I have so far to do this is:

```
june=[]    
for csv1 in glob.glob(path+'\\'+'*.csv'):
        if csv1[-10:-8] == '06':
            june.append(csv1)
            dfs={i: pd.DataFrame.from_csv(i) for i in june}
            panel=pd.Panel(dfs)
            panels=panel.replace(-999.9,np.NaN)
            dfs_mean=panels.mean(axis=0)
```

I have seen questions where the user is getting the same error, but the solutions for those questions doesn't seem to work with my issue. Any help fixing this, or ideas for a better approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does each file contain the same year, month, day?  Do you want those averaged as well?

Comment: Each file is for one day (so same year, month and day throughout each .csv), but the folder where all the files are located contains all of the files for a year (i.e. I have a folder for 2010, 2011, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pd.Panel` has been deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#deprecate-panel)
Use `pd.concat` with a dictionary comprehension and take the mean over level 1.

```
df1 = pd.concat({f: pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob('meansample[0-9].csv')})
df1.mean(level=1)

   Year   Month   Day   Latitude   Longitude   Value1   Value 2
0  2010       6     1         23          97        1       3.5
1  2010       6     1         24          97        5       8.2
2  2010       6     1         25          97        6       4.6
3  2010       6     1         26          97        4       2.0
```

Comment: This worked for me, with some minor changes to account for nodata values (given value of -999.9) for correct averages.

`june = pd.concat({f: pd.read_csv(f,na_values=[-999.9]) for f in glob.glob(path+'\\'+'*.csv')})`

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion to change the approach a bit. Instead of converting each DF into panel, just concat them into one big DF but for each one give a unique ID. After you can just do groupby by the ID and use mean() to get the result.

It would look similar to this:

```
import Pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
for csv1 in glob.glob(path+'\\'+'*.csv'):
    if csv1[-10:-8] == '06':
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(csv1)
        temp_df['df_id'] = csv1
        df = pd.concat([df, temp_df])
df.replace(-999.9, np.nan)
df = df.groupby("df_id").mean()
```

I hope it helps somehow, if you still have any issues with that let me know.